# Upgrading to Windows 8 for touchscreen

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

I am thinking of upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8 just for the touchscreen capability. The reason is to get user interaction and input nearly like as with a tablet, only with a Windows PC and touchscreen LCD.

I have Windows 7, and I've read that it already has touchscreen support. I was wondering if the touch capabilities of Windows 8 are enough of an improvement to justify upgrading. Also, can Windows 8 take input from *any* stylus (like from a Samsung Galaxy Tablet)?

Comment: Win8's definitely built for touch; Win7's touch capabilities aren't in any way comparable. As for stylus support, that would depend primarily on your touchscreen and whether it is resistive or capacitive. The OS just reacts to the touch events generated.

Comment: As magicandre1981 points out System Builder will only work on certified equipment, if you want touch support on non-Windows 8 touchscreen hardware you would have to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 using the upgrade license.

Answer (score 1):

The touch functionality is disabled if you buy the OEM/SB version of Windows 8:

> In order to promote the best “touch” experience on PCs, **OEM System
>   Builder software for Windows 8 will only support touch functionality
>   on hardware that has been certified for touch in Windows 8**. When
>   buying Windows 8 System Builder software, look for hardware that
>   carries the “Windows 8 Compatible” logo and that has passed
>   certification for touch capability. **Touch hardware that is not
>   certified for Windows 8 and does not include a special code provided
>   to OEMs during the certification process and injected into the
>   touchscreen’s firmware will not work once the System Builder product
>   is installed**; meaning that the PC will not be touch-enabled after
>   Windows 8 is installed. Whenever customers are looking to upgrade a
>   touch PC with a previous version of Windows, they should be directed
>   to purchase the retail Windows 8 Upgrade SKUs. In addition, we
>   recommend customers who are considering the Windows 8 System Builder
>   product should be advised about the touch limitation to avoid any
>   potential dissatisfaction. Remember that purchasing Windows 8 System
>   Builder software for personal use does not come with support from
>   Microsoft.

http://www.borncity.com/blog/2012/11/01/are-systembuilder-oem-skus-of-windows-8-are-not-a-full-windows-8/

So you need the retail version. To test if touch works in Win8, try the 90 day Enterprise Trial. This version should not have any limitations.

Comment: Technically all are the same. The only difference is licensing and this causes the touch screen issue. And in stores you get Retail most time. And retail contains both disks (32 and 64Bit) while OEM/SB only comes with one.

Comment: My personal experience i have only seen `Upgrade` and Windows 8 Core System Builder licenses in stores. The System Builder is suppose to be the "stand alone" product, in a case where, the person didn't have an eligible Windows installation already installed which isn't the case for these touch based systems.

Answer (score 0):

This depends.. If you want to use it for daily stuff (email, word, music, video) I would upgrade. If you are more technical or a gamer, the answer may be different. Windows 8 is tough to use if you like to get to the guts and bones of it. on the other hand if you are not a 'poweruser' it will be perfect! especially because you can use that fancy touch monitor!

Comment: Win8's perfect for non-power users but "tough" to use for power users/gamers?! Oh well, guess that's your perception of it.